# how to insert numbering that is linked to styles ms word c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I'm creating an application that is working with word automation. I'm using visual studio 2010, Microsoft word 2010 and working with interop.

I got the following 3 styles in my word document.

[image]

As you can see I have formatted the styles so that they get on their own level when doing numbering.
What I would like the application to do is to open an already existing document with numbered bullets (the app can do that) and then add some more (see picture).

[image]

So far I've tried this but it doesn't seem to follow the format that I've put in the style manually.

```
    public void insertTextHeading(Word.Document document, string bookmark, string text, int fontSize, string headingType, int listNumber, int bulletLevel)
    {
        var start = document.Bookmarks[bookmark].Start;
        var end = document.Bookmarks[bookmark].End;
        Word.Range range = document.Range(start, end);

        //The text design
        range.Font.Name = "Verdana";
        range.Font.Size = fontSize;
        range.set_Style(headingType);

        object n = listNumber;
        Word.ListTemplate template =
            document.Application.ListGalleries[Word.WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery].ListTemplates.get_Item(ref n);

        object bContinuePrevList = true;
        object applyTo = Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToSelection;
        object defBehavior = Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
        template, ref bContinuePrevList,
        ref applyTo, ref defBehavior, ref missing);
        range.Text = text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it turns out that the answer to your own question is that you're an idiot.
After a couple of hours I decided to debug every line of code I had and it turns out that the styles I've added manually to the word template creates the numbering itself. So I've tried to add the numbering by code when all I had to do was to tell the text to be inserted as the style I wanted.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same result, by modifying the styles, and then applying those styles, but am running into issues. If you have a few moments can you share how your code works? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353021/multiple-heading-styles-using-the-same-multilevel-list-style