# Multiple heading styles using the same multilevel list style

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to assign numbering to multiple heading styles in Word, so that I get content like the following:

```
6. <Heading 1>
6.1. <Heading 2>
6.1.1. <Heading 3>
6.2. <Heading 2>
6.2.1. <Heading 3>
6.3. <Heading 2>
```

You can do this pretty easily in standard Word by using the second multilevel numbering style (ignoring 'None'), the one that looks like this:

```
1.
1.1.
1.1.1.
```

But I'm trying to do this dynamically, by applying the second multilevel numbering style in code, and it comes out like this:

```
6. <Heading 1>
1.1 <Heading 2>
1.1.1 <Heading 3>
7. <Heading 1>
1.2 <Heading 2>
1.1.2 <Heading 3>
```

If I apply the second multilevel numbering style manually after this, it changes to the desired output.

Here is my code (a bit simplified but not by much).

```
ListGallery gallery = doc.Application.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery];
ListTemplate numberedTemplate = gallery.ListTemplates[2];
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
  Style style = doc.Styles["Heading " + i];
  style.LinkToListTemplate(numberedTemplate, i);
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on using a List Gallery. Instead, record a macro while defining a custom List Style (Template). That will produce the code for all 9 levels (even if you don't change or need them, the macro records them) and include linking the style to the Heading levels.

Comment: Why a macro? I was initially doing this with a custom ListTemplate (in code) and saw the same thing. I removed that part to try to narrow down the cause. That would basically be equivalent to a macro, yes?

Comment: If you don't understand how to create the correct outline level numbering settings then it's really more of an end-user question... Look in the dialog box where you define the various list levels. What you're missing is the "restart numbering after level *n*" setting for the second and third levels.

Comment: That does seem to work. It's not an answer to the actual question but if you convert that to an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: You don't actually ask a question, you know... :-) I felt it better to address the underlying problem rather than trying to patch-up a (IMO) less than optimal approach.  The reason the manual approach works is because the flaw in the list template used by the UI has been fixed in the version you're using, but the original, incorrect behavior is still in the object model enum. You'd have to go in an fix the ListTemplate - but for reasons explained in my "Answer" you're better off creating a custom ListTemplate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ListGalleries is not reliable/robust. In the case of indexes (choosing a number format from the list in the UI) you can't be sure the content of the list is always the same - that drawback is obvious.

The problem with the built-in galleries, such as you're using, is that this particular one has a "bug" (as it did in the UI when first released): levels 2 and 3 don't have the "Restart List After" setting activated, so you get the described behavior.

For that reason, it's better to record a macro while creating a custom list, preferably using "Define New List Style" from the outline numbering menu. You can then use the code anywhere.

Defining a named List Style will give you a named List Template, which means it can be re-used and managed directly. (In your code you use an index value to reference a ListTemplate, which can go wrong if the one you intend to use is not the second one in the collection.)